# Seven of Nine's Singing Voice

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

When Seven and the Doctor sing 'You Are My Sunshine' and 'My Darling Clementine',  is that really Jeri Ryan singing?

I know she's really singing 'It Can't Be Wrong' but she sounds kinda different on the other two.

Comment: It certainly sounds like her.

Comment: Not sure if it means anything, but I can't see anything about voice-overs or singers in the credits on imdb:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708971/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm... i feel like if there was it would have been listed. and if she is really singing one song she is likely singing the others as well.

Comment: Maybe they are slightly autotuned?

Comment: IIRC she sings it cant be wrong in the holodeck while she believes she is a character in the program she sings the other two to humor the doctor in one case and her higher brain functions are being suppressed the the other which would probably lead to the singing sounding different

Answer (score 12):

According to a twit from Jeri Ryan, the singing on the show was all her.

> **Q.** *Binge watching Voyager! Was it you singing and playing piano on the show? Your voice is beautiful*
>
> **@JeriLRyan:** *Singing, yes. Piano, no.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/jerilryan/statuses/773405619881672704/?lang=en)</sup></sub>

For the record, Jeri Ryan was a keen singer from an early age and her 'pageant talent' was the song "[On My Own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_My_Own_(Les_Mis%C3%A9rables))" from Les Miserables